# How to tell if my program is running on cores and/or threads (slurm/mpirun, htop)

Tags: slurm, openmpi, htop

I am attempting to run a parallelized (OpenMPI) program on 48 *cores*, but am unable to tell without ambiguity whether I am truly running on cores or threads. I am using `htop` to try to illuminate core/thread usage, but it's output lacks sufficient description to fully deduce how the program is running.

I have a workstation with 2x Intel Xeon Gold 6248R, each with 24 cores and threaded---so, 48 total cores, 96 total threads. I have a program parallelized using OpenMPI which I want to have run on all 48 processors, using 1 thread per processor. I am employing Slurm on this workstation to schedule jobs.

First, I have configured Slurm to reflect the system architecture. From the bottom of `slurm.conf`:

```
...
# COMPUTE NODES
NodeName=name Sockets=2 CoresPerSocket=24 ThreadsPerCore=2 State=UNKNOWN
PartitionName=primary Nodes=ALL Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```

I am submitting jobs to Slurm via the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -J jobname
#SBATCH -e error.%A
#SBATCH -o output.%A
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=48
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=48
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-core=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-socket=24
#SBATCH --threads-per-core=1

mpirun -np 48 binary.x
```

...and indeed, the processor is printing 48 output files (as expected).

So, the question is: how do I know that I am truly running on all 48 *processors*, rather than 48 *threads* on 24 processors? Sure, the Slurm script above is rather explicit, but it is something I want to be sure of before batch processing 1000 simulations.

The primary issue that is making me uncertain is using `htop`. The following displays a typical/representative snapshot of what is being reported (it jumps around a bit, of course):
[representative htop output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMQdS.png)

The problem is that, for the most part, `htop` is saying that most of the activity is occurring on 0-47. So, the next question is: how is `htop` printing cores/threads? One would expect they would be printed in pairs (i.e., the two threads for core 1 would be 0-1, the two threads for core 2 would be 2-3, and so on), but I cannot find this documented anywhere. Output from `lstopo` (hwloc), below, indicates this could be the case (if we follow `PU` numbers...), but I am not sure if these are linked / drawing the same info.

Any hints would be welcome, either with regard to knowing `htop`'s output, to constructing a better Slurm script, or both.

`lstopo` output:

```
Machine (125GB total)
  NUMANode L#0 (P#0 62GB)
    Package L#0 + L3 L#0 (36MB)
      L2 L#0 (1024KB) + L1d L#0 (32KB) + L1i L#0 (32KB) + Core L#0
        PU L#0 (P#0)
        PU L#1 (P#48)
      L2 L#1 (1024KB) + L1d L#1 (32KB) + L1i L#1 (32KB) + Core L#1
        PU L#2 (P#1)
        PU L#3 (P#49)
      L2 L#2 (1024KB) + L1d L#2 (32KB) + L1i L#2 (32KB) + Core L#2
        PU L#4 (P#2)
        PU L#5 (P#50)
      L2 L#3 (1024KB) + L1d L#3 (32KB) + L1i L#3 (32KB) + Core L#3
        PU L#6 (P#3)
        PU L#7 (P#51)
      L2 L#4 (1024KB) + L1d L#4 (32KB) + L1i L#4 (32KB) + Core L#4
        PU L#8 (P#4)
        PU L#9 (P#52)
      L2 L#5 (1024KB) + L1d L#5 (32KB) + L1i L#5 (32KB) + Core L#5
        PU L#10 (P#5)
        PU L#11 (P#53)
      L2 L#6 (1024KB) + L1d L#6 (32KB) + L1i L#6 (32KB) + Core L#6
        PU L#12 (P#6)
        PU L#13 (P#54)
      L2 L#7 (1024KB) + L1d L#7 (32KB) + L1i L#7 (32KB) + Core L#7
        PU L#14 (P#7)
        PU L#15 (P#55)
      L2 L#8 (1024KB) + L1d L#8 (32KB) + L1i L#8 (32KB) + Core L#8
        PU L#16 (P#8)
        PU L#17 (P#56)
      L2 L#9 (1024KB) + L1d L#9 (32KB) + L1i L#9 (32KB) + Core L#9
        PU L#18 (P#9)
        PU L#19 (P#57)
      L2 L#10 (1024KB) + L1d L#10 (32KB) + L1i L#10 (32KB) + Core L#10
        PU L#20 (P#10)
        PU L#21 (P#58)
      L2 L#11 (1024KB) + L1d L#11 (32KB) + L1i L#11 (32KB) + Core L#11
        PU L#22 (P#11)
        PU L#23 (P#59)
      L2 L#12 (1024KB) + L1d L#12 (32KB) + L1i L#12 (32KB) + Core L#12
        PU L#24 (P#12)
        PU L#25 (P#60)
      L2 L#13 (1024KB) + L1d L#13 (32KB) + L1i L#13 (32KB) + Core L#13
        PU L#26 (P#13)
        PU L#27 (P#61)
      L2 L#14 (1024KB) + L1d L#14 (32KB) + L1i L#14 (32KB) + Core L#14
        PU L#28 (P#14)
        PU L#29 (P#62)
      L2 L#15 (1024KB) + L1d L#15 (32KB) + L1i L#15 (32KB) + Core L#15
        PU L#30 (P#15)
        PU L#31 (P#63)
      L2 L#16 (1024KB) + L1d L#16 (32KB) + L1i L#16 (32KB) + Core L#16
        PU L#32 (P#16)
        PU L#33 (P#64)
      L2 L#17 (1024KB) + L1d L#17 (32KB) + L1i L#17 (32KB) + Core L#17
        PU L#34 (P#17)
        PU L#35 (P#65)
      L2 L#18 (1024KB) + L1d L#18 (32KB) + L1i L#18 (32KB) + Core L#18
        PU L#36 (P#18)
        PU L#37 (P#66)
      L2 L#19 (1024KB) + L1d L#19 (32KB) + L1i L#19 (32KB) + Core L#19
        PU L#38 (P#19)
        PU L#39 (P#67)
      L2 L#20 (1024KB) + L1d L#20 (32KB) + L1i L#20 (32KB) + Core L#20
        PU L#40 (P#20)
        PU L#41 (P#68)
      L2 L#21 (1024KB) + L1d L#21 (32KB) + L1i L#21 (32KB) + Core L#21
        PU L#42 (P#21)
        PU L#43 (P#69)
      L2 L#22 (1024KB) + L1d L#22 (32KB) + L1i L#22 (32KB) + Core L#22
        PU L#44 (P#22)
        PU L#45 (P#70)
      L2 L#23 (1024KB) + L1d L#23 (32KB) + L1i L#23 (32KB) + Core L#23
        PU L#46 (P#23)
        PU L#47 (P#71)
    HostBridge L#0
      PCI 8086:a1d2
      PCI 8086:a1bc
      PCI 8086:2826
      PCIBridge
        PCI 8086:1533
          Net L#0 "enp2s0"
      PCI 8086:15b9
        Net L#1 "enp0s31f6"
    HostBridge L#2
      PCI 8086:201d
    HostBridge L#3
      PCIBridge
        PCI 1000:0017
          Block(Disk) L#2 "sdb"
          Block(Disk) L#3 "sda"
      PCI 8086:201d
    HostBridge L#5
      PCIBridge
        PCI 10de:24b0
          GPU L#4 "renderD128"
          GPU L#5 "controlD64"
          GPU L#6 "card0"
  NUMANode L#1 (P#1 63GB)
    Package L#1 + L3 L#1 (36MB)
      L2 L#24 (1024KB) + L1d L#24 (32KB) + L1i L#24 (32KB) + Core L#24
        PU L#48 (P#24)
        PU L#49 (P#72)
      L2 L#25 (1024KB) + L1d L#25 (32KB) + L1i L#25 (32KB) + Core L#25
        PU L#50 (P#25)
        PU L#51 (P#73)
      L2 L#26 (1024KB) + L1d L#26 (32KB) + L1i L#26 (32KB) + Core L#26
        PU L#52 (P#26)
        PU L#53 (P#74)
      L2 L#27 (1024KB) + L1d L#27 (32KB) + L1i L#27 (32KB) + Core L#27
        PU L#54 (P#27)
        PU L#55 (P#75)
      L2 L#28 (1024KB) + L1d L#28 (32KB) + L1i L#28 (32KB) + Core L#28
        PU L#56 (P#28)
        PU L#57 (P#76)
      L2 L#29 (1024KB) + L1d L#29 (32KB) + L1i L#29 (32KB) + Core L#29
        PU L#58 (P#29)
        PU L#59 (P#77)
      L2 L#30 (1024KB) + L1d L#30 (32KB) + L1i L#30 (32KB) + Core L#30
        PU L#60 (P#30)
        PU L#61 (P#78)
      L2 L#31 (1024KB) + L1d L#31 (32KB) + L1i L#31 (32KB) + Core L#31
        PU L#62 (P#31)
        PU L#63 (P#79)
      L2 L#32 (1024KB) + L1d L#32 (32KB) + L1i L#32 (32KB) + Core L#32
        PU L#64 (P#32)
        PU L#65 (P#80)
      L2 L#33 (1024KB) + L1d L#33 (32KB) + L1i L#33 (32KB) + Core L#33
        PU L#66 (P#33)
        PU L#67 (P#81)
      L2 L#34 (1024KB) + L1d L#34 (32KB) + L1i L#34 (32KB) + Core L#34
        PU L#68 (P#34)
        PU L#69 (P#82)
      L2 L#35 (1024KB) + L1d L#35 (32KB) + L1i L#35 (32KB) + Core L#35
        PU L#70 (P#35)
        PU L#71 (P#83)
      L2 L#36 (1024KB) + L1d L#36 (32KB) + L1i L#36 (32KB) + Core L#36
        PU L#72 (P#36)
        PU L#73 (P#84)
      L2 L#37 (1024KB) + L1d L#37 (32KB) + L1i L#37 (32KB) + Core L#37
        PU L#74 (P#37)
        PU L#75 (P#85)
      L2 L#38 (1024KB) + L1d L#38 (32KB) + L1i L#38 (32KB) + Core L#38
        PU L#76 (P#38)
        PU L#77 (P#86)
      L2 L#39 (1024KB) + L1d L#39 (32KB) + L1i L#39 (32KB) + Core L#39
        PU L#78 (P#39)
        PU L#79 (P#87)
      L2 L#40 (1024KB) + L1d L#40 (32KB) + L1i L#40 (32KB) + Core L#40
        PU L#80 (P#40)
        PU L#81 (P#88)
      L2 L#41 (1024KB) + L1d L#41 (32KB) + L1i L#41 (32KB) + Core L#41
        PU L#82 (P#41)
        PU L#83 (P#89)
      L2 L#42 (1024KB) + L1d L#42 (32KB) + L1i L#42 (32KB) + Core L#42
        PU L#84 (P#42)
        PU L#85 (P#90)
      L2 L#43 (1024KB) + L1d L#43 (32KB) + L1i L#43 (32KB) + Core L#43
        PU L#86 (P#43)
        PU L#87 (P#91)
      L2 L#44 (1024KB) + L1d L#44 (32KB) + L1i L#44 (32KB) + Core L#44
        PU L#88 (P#44)
        PU L#89 (P#92)
      L2 L#45 (1024KB) + L1d L#45 (32KB) + L1i L#45 (32KB) + Core L#45
        PU L#90 (P#45)
        PU L#91 (P#93)
      L2 L#46 (1024KB) + L1d L#46 (32KB) + L1i L#46 (32KB) + Core L#46
        PU L#92 (P#46)
        PU L#93 (P#94)
      L2 L#47 (1024KB) + L1d L#47 (32KB) + L1i L#47 (32KB) + Core L#47
        PU L#94 (P#47)
        PU L#95 (P#95)
    HostBridge L#7
      PCI 8086:201d
```